# form with a table with out form in a different table

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I have a php page which I echo some html in it.

in this page I have a table(1) with and in this table(2) I want to create another form table without having to mess up the original table(1). The structure atm looks like this

```
<table>
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is

```
 <table>
     <form>//form1

     </form>
  <table>
      <form>//form2

     </form>
  </table>
</table>
```

but it `inspect element` I am am getting `<form></form>` in the form 2 anything of the `input` in form2 doesn't stay within the form2 tab. P.S. I have used  `tr` and `td` for the `input` but still the `input` is still out of place.

anything idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not contain a real example of what you tried because it does not have the `<tr> , <td> <input>` etc so I can't tell what you did wrong, but here is a [simple working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ER8L6/)

Next time, try to add some problematic code so we can tell you what you did wrong, this way you'll learn how to write your code correctly.